# Cannot use android-maps-utils in module

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-maps-utils

I have a project which contains two modules; the `main` app module and another module which I include in the app module, let's call this module myModule.

I want to use SphericalUtil in myModule, which is included in android-maps-utils, so I've added `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'` to the build.gradle file belonging to `myModule`.

The strange thing is that I cannot import any classes belonging to the android-maps-utils library, it seems to just not exist in myModule, even though I get no gradle errors. When I type SphericalUtil in any of the classes belonging to myModule I get the suggestion to '`Add library android-maps-utils to classpath`', but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

When I add the exact same line in the app module gradle file, it does seem to work. I can type `SphericalUtil` in any class belonging to the app module and Android Studio recognizes the class and allows me to auto-import it.

I've also tried with a different library, e.g. okhttp, but no issues there, I can autoimport and use it in myModule, so the issue seems to be correlated to `android-maps-utils`. Maybe following the suggestion to add the library to the classpath broke things? I'm really out of guesses, so any help is really appriciated.

If it helps, myModule gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/android
    compileOnly group: 'com.google.android', name: 'android', version: '4.1.1.4'

    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'

    compile files('libs/experiment.resultlogger-0.0.2.jar')
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Comment: Did you add MyModule to the settings.gralde file? like so: include ':MyModule'

Comment: Yes, I did. It says:`include ':app', ':myModule'`

Comment: Can you please post your MyModule build.gralde file?

Comment: Just added it to my original post

Comment: Try adding this to the top of the gradle file and then sync/build the project: apply plugin: 'com.android.library' , it might need the android { ... } thing

Comment: Adding this causes a whole lot of other issues. It expects an AndroidManifest.xml in myModule, which I've added (just copied manifest from app module). But then the module expects a toplevel activity (e.g. MainActivity), which I don't have in myModule, because I wanted to build myModule as a non-native-Android module to also be able to use it in native Java applications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165482/discussion-between-hed-shafran-and-daan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Android module plugin instead of java plugin. As the [following documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) says:

> To create a new library module in your project, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Click File > New > New Module.
> 2. In the Create New Module window that appears, click Android Library, then click Next.   There's also an option to create a Java
>    Library, which builds a traditional JAR file. **While a JAR file is
>    useful for many projects—especially when you want to share code with
>    other platforms—it does not allow you to include Android resources or
>    manifest files, which is very useful for code reuse in Android
>    projects.** So this guide focuses on creating Android libraries.
>
> 3.Give your library a name and select a minimum SDK version for the code in the library, then click Finish.

To tackle the AndroidManifest.xml problem, you can use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.your.library"/>
```

Comment: If I create it as an Android Library, can I use the library in native Java applications? Because I want to use the library also in non-Android projects.

Comment: You can't use android library for Java application. And you also can't use `android-maps-utils` for Java application because it's only for Android application.